# '90s movie involving a bag of marbles, a werewolf, and a woman

Tags: story-identification, movie, werewolf

There was a movie back in the '90s that my mom would watch when it came on. I barely remember it, but I know bits and pieces of it.

In part of the movie, there was a bag of marbles, and all the, I want to say, mothers who picked a ‘regular’ marble were safe, while the one who picked a different marble had her son chosen for something?

At the end of the movie, a werewolf impregnated a woman; they were together and I’m not sure if she was 100% human.

I’ve been thinking about this movie a lot lately, and my mom does not remember it.

Comment: Possibly *The Company of Wolves*? But I don't remember anything to do with marbles.

Answer (score 1):

*[Storm of the Century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_of_the_Century)* by Stephen King (not based on one of his books or stories) came out in 1999 and includes a scene where stones are drawn. There is no werewolf, but there is a fellow with a walking stick with a wolf's head.

> Mike begs the town to refuse, arguing the villain is not all-powerful and may soon leave the town just as the storm will if they trust in God and their own power. He appeals to their common decency and points out they may be aiding an evil man in harming a child. The other townspeople, including Mike's wife Molly, are too frightened of Linoge and think they have no choice. They argue this is not human sacrifice but rather an "adoption" and it is better to lose one child rather than all. Mike wishes to abstain from voting and take Ralphie away, but his friends stop him and Molly insists that being part of the town means they must accept Ralphie may be the child taken. Everyone but Mike votes in favor to give Linoge what he desires, and Hatch says he will see this is the right decision. Linoge arrives and has one parent of each child draw one of eight "weirding stones" that predate the sinking of Atlantis. Molly draws the lone black stone, marking Ralphie as the one who will be taken. Linoge transforms into his true form and thanks the town, suggesting they will be better off if they do not reveal his existence or this arrangement to the outside world. Mike is held back by Hatch and other townsfolk who fear reprisal. Now regretting her choice, Molly frantically cries at Mike to help save Ralphie; but the townspeople continue to restrain him and refuse to aid her. In anguish, Molly madly accuses Linoge of tricking them by fixing the result of the stones before she attacks him in a frenzy. Linoge merely knocks Molly aside and remarks that she and the townspeople may have all tricked themselves, adding that Ralphie will eventually call him "father." Carrying the child, Linoge flies off into the night.

### The Stones Scene